# Many forms per page ajax laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to save the results without refreshing the whole page. I have multiple forms and I need to save the data of the one which clicked on the "submit" button.

At the moment, everything is saved, but it refreshes the whole page.

blog.partials._comment_replies.blade

```
@foreach($comment as $comments)

     <form method="post" class="formmmmmmmmmmm">
         {{ csrf_field() }}
         <input class="form-text form-item__input" type="text" id="form-field-id" name="comment_body" value="" size="60" maxlength="128">
         <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> 
     </form>

     @include('blog.partials._comment_replies', ['comment' =>$comments->replies])
@endforeach
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formmmmmmmmmmm').on('click',function(e) {
        var form = $(this);
        var submit = form.find("[type=submit]");
        var submitOriginalText = submit.attr("value");

        e.preventDefault();

        var data = form.serialize();
        var url = form.attr('action');
        var post = form.attr('method');

        if (jQuery(".formmmmmmmmmmm").length > 0) {
            $(".formmmmmmmmmmm").validate({

            rules: {
                comment_body: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 100
                },  
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: "Please enter name",
                    maxlength: "Your last name maxlength should be 100 characters long."
                }, 
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                 $.ajaxSetup({
                      headers: {
                          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                      }
                  });
                  jQuery('#send_form').html('Sending..');
                  $.ajax({
                        url:"{{ route('reply.add') }}",
                        type: "POST",
                        data :data,
                        success: function( data ) {
                            submit.attr("value", "Submitted");
                        },
                        beforeSend: function(){
                            submit.attr("value", "Loading...");
                            submit.prop("disabled", true);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            submit.attr("value", submitOriginalText);
                            submit.prop("disabled", false);
                            // show error to end user
                        }
                    });
                }
            }); 
        };
    });
});
```

comment controller

```
public function replyStore(Request $request)
{
     $reply = new Comment;
     $reply->body = $request->get('comment_body');

     $reply->user()->associate($request->user());
     $reply->parent_id = $request->get('comment_id');

     $post = Article::find($request->get('article_id'));

     $check = $post->comment()->save($reply);
     $arr = array('msg' => 'Something goes to wrong. Please try again lator', 'status' => false);
     if ($check) { 
         $arr = array('msg' => 'Successfully submit form using ajaxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'status' => true);
     }
     return Response()->json($arr);   
}
```

Comment: you dont need action for form when using ajax to save data, submit will redirect it to that action.  just change submit to button, and on click event change submit to click, ajax url is your action url , so make these changes

Comment: I edit answer. Pleace check it . it's doent work

Comment: also change this `$('.formmmmmmmmmmm').on('submit',function(e){` to `$('.formmmmmmmmmmm').on('click',function(e){` and in your form          `<input type="submit"`  to          `<input type="button" `

Comment: it's not help me.

Comment: Please share more details. The given markup contains only a single form

Comment: @NicoHaase edit my question. Please check it. help

Comment: I still don't get your question. According to the title, you have "many forms per page", but you haven't shown any markup for that. Additionally, what have you tried to debug your problem? Where do you supress the usual form submission?

Comment: @NicoHaase  You see, there is a cycle that creates these forms until the comments end? and on the page there are a lot of forms

Comment: Ah, okay, haven't seen that. Then please be warned that problems might arise through multiple usages of an HTML element with the same ID `form-field-id`. So, what have you tried to debug the problem? Where do you handle form **submissions** in all that code? There's only a pretty long `click` handler

Comment: in script code. I want check this validate and after call url `{{ route('reply.add') }}`  it's `replyStore` function name in the web.php
Yes, this is due to repeated indicators and so on. I need to save data from the form where I click on the button

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's fix your invalid HTML. Every element in DOM should be using unique id. So, make it unique (e.g. using comment id or you can even remove it if you're not using). Plus, we need to change input type to `submit`. And you don't have to specify form method here.

```
@foreach($comment as $comments)

     <form class="formmmmmmmmmmm">
         @csrf
         <input class="form-text form-item__input" type="text" id="form-field-id-{{ $comment->id }}" name="comment_body" value="" size="60" maxlength="128">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"> 
     </form>

    @include('blog.partials._comment_replies', ['comment' =>$comments->replies])
@endforeach
```

And then, we need to update form submit handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.formmmmmmmmmmm').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const form = $(this);

        let submit = form.find('[type=submit]');
        let submitOriginalText = submit.attr('value');
        let data = form.serialize();

        form.validate({
            rules: {
                comment_body: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 100
                },
            },
            messages: {
                name: {
                    required: 'Please enter name',
                    maxlength: 'Your last name maxlength should be 100 characters long.'
                }, 
            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                $('#send_form').html('Sending...');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ route('reply.add') }}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: data,
                    success: function( data ) {
                        submit.attr('value', 'Submitted');
                    },
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        submit.attr('value', 'Loading...');
                        submit.prop('disabled', true);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        submit.attr('value', submitOriginalText);
                        submit.prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Removed unnecessary variables (`url`, `post`) and form existence check. This should submit a single form at a time without refreshing the page.

Comment: What happens when you submit the form? Any error messages on the console?

Comment: since my script is written in the blade, I get the error "template error", but I have other scripts in it and they work fine. And secondly, the page reloads at the click of a button

Comment: Then try to separate your template files instead of including the same file in self.